# MSXML2.XMLHTTP - Vista performance

Tags: performance, vb6, windows-vista, msxml

I have the following (simple) VB6 code:

```
Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument30
Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument30

Dim xmlRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP40
Set xmlRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP40

xmlRequest.open "GET", "http://myserver.com/Service.svc/models/20080101", False
xmlRequest.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding:", "gzip/deflate"
xmlRequest.send

xmlDoc.loadXML xmlRequest.responseText
```

which downloads a bunch of stuff from a web service I wrote.

In an XP VM (Virtual PC) running on my main machine, this code executes and returns data from the web service in ~4 seconds. However, if compiled and the resulting exe run on my main machine (Vista x64) it takes 20+ seconds to return data from the web service.

Can anyone shed any light on why this might be the case?

Comment: Can you step through your code and tell what specific line takes so long to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, just had a thought - which proved to be correct. Doh!

It turned out to be Avast! Anti-Virus slowing things down.